# How do I control PDF paper size with ImageMagick?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick

I have 16 jpg files which are around 920x1200 pixels (the widths slightly differ but heights are all 1200). I'm trying to join them into a pdf with:

```
convert *.jpg foo.pdf
```

But the resulting paper size is 1.53x2 inches. If I pass the arguments `-page Letter`, the page size ends up being a bewildering 1.02x1.32 inches. What is going wrong here? All of the information I can find suggests that this should work. I just want a document that consists of 16 letter-size pages.

Answer (score 55):

This question is pretty old, but I had a similar problem and I think I found the solution.

The documentation for the -page option says "This option is used in concert with -density", but the relationship between the options seems a little unclear, possibly because the documentation is geared towards raster images.

From experimenting with the settings, I found that the pdf page size can be controlled by combining -page -density and -units. The [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) for -page shows that letter is the same as entering 612 x 792. Combining -density 72 with -units pixelsperinch will give you (612px /72px) * 1in = 8.5in.

`convert *.jpg -units pixelsperinch -density 72 -page letter foo.pdf` should do what the original poster wanted.

Comment: Thanks to your post I understood that the unities given in `page` are not absolute, but related to the `density`. The page size in inches is the `page_length_parameter / density`

Comment: For people who just want a PDF file made of their images, where the PDF page matches the image size and shape: `convert -page 1678x1048 slide*.png presentation.pdf` where `1678x1048` is the WIDTHxHEIGHT of your images in pixels.

Comment: This cripples the image by resampling it into 72 dpi instead of keeping its input resolution.

Answer (score 14):

I just succeeded with
`convert file.mng -page letter file.pdf`

Comment: This won't scale (shrink/expand) each image to optimally fit on page size.

Comment: For European sizes it's `-page a4`, for landscape... well. try `-rotate 90`

Answer (score 9):

For Letter, you need to specify the size as 792x612 PostScript points. Therefor try this command:

```
 convert \
    in1.jpg \
    in2.jpg \
    in3.jpg \
    in4.jpg \
    in5.jpg \
   -gravity center \
   -resize 792x612\! \
    letter.pdf
```

Works for me with ImageMagick version *6.7.8-3 2012-07-19 Q16* on Mac OS X:

```
identify -format "%f[%s] :  %W x %H\n" letter.pdf
  letter.pdf[0] :  792 x 612
  letter.pdf[1] :  792 x 612
  letter.pdf[2] :  792 x 612
  letter.pdf[3] :  792 x 612
  letter.pdf[4] :  792 x 612
```

Or

```
pdfinfo -f 1 -l 5 letter.pdf 
  Title:          _
  Producer:       ImageMagick 6.7.8-3 2012-07-19 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
  CreationDate:   Fri Jul 27 22:28:00 2012
  ModDate:        Fri Jul 27 22:28:00 2012
  Tagged:         no
  Form:           none
  Pages:          5
  Encrypted:      no
  Page    1 size: 792 x 612 pts (letter)
  Page    1 rot:  0
  Page    2 size: 792 x 612 pts (letter)
  Page    2 rot:  0
  Page    3 size: 792 x 612 pts (letter)
  Page    3 rot:  0
  Page    4 size: 792 x 612 pts (letter)
  Page    4 rot:  0
  Page    5 size: 792 x 612 pts (letter)
  Page    5 rot:  0
  File size:      178642 bytes
  Optimized:      no
  PDF version:    1.3
```

Comment: That resulted in a distorted, more square-ish aspect ratio, and the page size says 1.32x1.02 inch.

Comment: Which version of IM are you using? (run `convert -version` to find out)

Comment: How did you determine the page size as being '1.32x1.02 inch' ?

Comment: It's 6.5.7-8 on Ubuntu. I actually managed to muddle with `-density` to get the document size close enough to letter size. With `-density 109`, the pages end up around 606-617pts wide and 793pts tall, which evince accepts as being close enough to call it US Letter.

Comment: I was using evince's File->Properties to check the page size.

Comment: And for readers not in the US, who will likely be unfamiliar with 'postscript points', 'inches' and 'Letter': the United States has its own anachronistic system of lengths, and its own paper sizes, too. But you can use Google to convert to the 'postscript points' that ImageMagick uses, e.g. search for '297mm in postscript points' to eventually arrive at `-resize 842x595`. However, most standard paper sizes also work, e.g. `-resize A4`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density), 72 dpi is the default density => one dot per pixel (for a computer screen).

So you just need to specify `-units pixelsperinch`.

You can type the following command :

```
$ convert *.jpg -units pixelsperinch -page letter foo.pdf
```

BTW : If you want to use a non standard page size such as `A4R` for example, you must first determine the page size in dots (or pixels given at 72dpi) :

```
$ paperconf -s -p A4
595.276 841.89
```

Then the `-page` argument for `A4R` will be `842x595`

Comment: I wouldn’t call A4R “non-standard”, considering that A4 [is the most common page size](https://vividmaps.com/paper-sizes-world-map/) and the only standard in most countries.

Answer (score 0):

When you'll print them, your printer will probably not use more than 300 DPI, so you can save space (and printer processing time) by turning them to that resolution using `-density 300x300`.

You'll also probably want the PDF to match the paper size, no matter what the input files' sizes may be (and the original aspect ratio preserved), by using `-resize` and `-extent` with the paper size in pixels (and align them as you'd like with `-gravity`).

You may also want to put all of them in portrait mode by using `-rotate "90>"`.

So here's my proposal:

```
$ convert *.jpg \
    -rotate "90>" \
    -gravity center \
    -units PixelsPerInch -density 300x300 \
    -resize 2551x3295 -extent 2551x3295 \
    foo.pdf
```

For US Letter, use `2551x3295`; for A4, use `2480x3508`.

Comment: Of all the answers here, this is the only one that works for me (and it's been marked down!) The "-extent" option rather than "-page" seems to be the key. I used 200dpi, and happy with very low quality images (just receipts), so ended up using `convert -quality 30 *.jpg -gravity center -units pixelsperinch -density 200 -resize 1652x2338 -extent 1652x2338 out.pdf`. Thank you.